# Next and Previous code malfunction on certain categories only

Tags: php, wordpress

I am totally at loss here. I have put a code in my function to enable a shortcode to do previous and next page/post by category.
I have 7 categories. In 3 categories I have done the shortcode works perfectly. but somehow it doesn't in 4th. I haven't tried other categories yet. I have put all pages at same publishing date, set the order of pages properly, have same parent folder, have same category. I even deleted the category and made new one thinking may have glitched.

Please help me I am so confused and really don't want to go back to do link from page to page.... 
My website is somaliforkids.com
The categories in Learn for numbers, alphabet and colour are fine.... It is the animal ones (https://somaliforkids.com/learn/animals/) that go nonesense ... no logic... It goes from page order 1 to 3 to 9 to 6 to 16. doesn't follow alphabet of title, dates...  I use Elementor in my page to put shortcodes.

Here is my code:

```
     // next   
   add_shortcode( 'prev', 'prev_shortcode' );
   add_shortcode( 'next', 'next_shortcode' );
   function next_shortcode($atts) {
    global $post;
    ob_start(); 
    next_post_link( '<div class="nav-next">%link</div>', '<img class="aligncenter" 
    src="https://somaliforkids.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/right-black.png" width="50" height="35">', 
   '%title <span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '→', 'Previous post link', 'morphology' ) . '</span>',
         true);              
    $result = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $result;
   }

   function prev_shortcode($atts) {
    global $post;
    ob_start();
    previous_post_link( '<div class="nav-previous">%link</div>', '<img class="aligncenter" 
   src="https://somaliforkids.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/left-black.png" width="50" height="35">', 
   '%title <span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '→', 'Previous post link', 'morphology' ) . '</span>',
         true );              
    $result = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $result;
   }
```

Thank you for your help,
Isabelle

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to create shortcodes for this, because wordpress already has the functions you need. You are just not using the parameters of them:

```
next_post_link();
previous_post_link();
```

When you read the functions code reference for next_post_link, you will see it accepts multiple parameters: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/next_post_link/

One of it is:

**$in_same_term(bool)**

(Optional) Whether link should be in a same taxonomy term.Default value: false

So you just have to put in your **single.php** file at your desired position:

```
<?php next_post_link( '%link', 'Next post in category', true ); ?>
```

Of course you can use your arrow black image etc... The true is for the $in_same_term parameter.

If you want to have the posts within a specific taxonomy, you can use:

```
<?php next_post_link( '%link', 'Next post in taxonomy', true, '', 'your_custom_taxonomy' ); ?>
```

See the ' ' with no value? This is for an array or comma-separated list of excluded term IDs, if you need them.

Hope this helps.